# Phonetic .txt file parsing

Tags: java, parsing, text

I am very new to Java. My question is how to parse data such as this: 
 [Image](http://i.imgur.com/KTnqGX3.png)

I need to parse just the lines beginning with "ALIGN_REF:" and "ALIGN_HYP:"

It is basically a pronunciation and those letters are phonetic letters (U: ? RR ...etc.)

The line ALIGN_REF is reference and ALIGN_HYP is what has been estimated. I only need these two lines.

What I basically need is to save every phoneme on the line (ALIGN_REF) and below (ALIGN_HYP). And according to these create a confusion matrix.

What function should I use to parse every single phoneme (probably into different arrays) just on those two lines?

Comment: Take a look at the `Scanner` class, especially the `skip()` method.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You should definitely include the content of the image as text in your question, ideally in `code` formatting. Your question will be simpler to understand. Also the text can serve as test input for possible solutions.

Comment: BufferedReader along with switch statement or if statements could do some magic

Answer (score 0):

I would parse each line and check if it begins with `ALIGN_REF` or `ALIGN_HYP`. If that is a match then you can read the whole line into 2 String objects. You can use `Scanner` to read from a file or the command line.

From here the `split` function in Java for String will split up the line, and you can use the space as a separator. The variable `alignHyp` below will have the corresponding line from your source data.

```
String[] alignHypArr = alignHyp.split(" ");
```

This array above will now have the different characters you require for the `ALIGN_HYP` line.

Comment: Ok, do I understand it correctly that in the alignHypArr will be after this one command the all characters (phonemes) which are between the spaces on that line? What I actually need next is to compare the character on align_refline with character on the same position of the align_hyp line...and for every such a character in align_ref calculate the amount of each character which has been estimated ...so that I actually have x*x table where are vertical and horizontal the same phones and in the cells is the number of occurences. Is it good way to model it with arrays?

Comment: So providing the lines are the same length (and always will be) the characters will be at the same index in each array, so a straight comparison can take place. From this you can do the calculation that you need to perform on the result.